# Atomic 128-bit Memory Mode Selection

Tags: c++, c, gcc, concurrency, atomic

Using gcc, my code has an atomic 128-bit integer than is being written to by one thread, and read concurrently from 31 threads. I don't care about operations on this variable's synchronization with any other memory in my program (i.e. I'm okay with the compiler reordering two writes to two different integers), as long as reads and writes from and to this variable are consistent. I just want the guarantee that the writes to the atomic 128-bit are "eventually" guaranteed to be reflected in the 31 threads reading from that variable.

Is it safe to use a relaxed memory model? What are the gotchas I should look out for?

Comment: First off, check whether the integer is lock-free. (I doubt it.) Generally, though, relaxed memory ordering doesn't provide synchronisation, so make sure you don't have any dependent data races.

Comment: The fact that it is one thread that writes doesn't make it more or less easier to make it thread-safe and atomic.  Whatever "relaxed" might mean, it is surely "no".

Comment: KerrekSB: what do you mean by "lock free"? Are you talking about the instruction prefix or whether or not I'm using mutexes?

HansPassant: relaxed as defined [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins).

Comment: "Lock-free" as exposed by the library function `is_lock_free`...

Comment: I'm not using c++11. Where do I find this `is_lock_free` function?

Comment: @ClarkGaebel: In C++, when you say "I have an atomic..." people are going to think `std::atomic`. After all, that's how you get atomic objects in C++. Since you aren't using that, it should be stated in your question which non-C++ extensions or methods you're using to handle your atomic objects.

Comment: [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins). Speaking of which, nevermind. Just found the is_lock_free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relaxed ordering does not guarantee that the value written by the writer thread will ever be visible to any of the reader threads.

It is valid behavior that the readers only ever see the initial value of the variable and none of the changes. However, it is guaranteed that a writer thread always sees at least the changes he himself made to the variable (and possibly, but again not guaranteed, any later change applied by another thread).

In other words: You still get sequential consistency *within a single thread*, but no consistency whatsoever between different threads.

Comment: Which memory mode should I use instead? Also, as a quick follow-up question: What's the point of "relaxed" mode?

Comment: You are guaranteed that once a reader thread sees a given store, it will never see an *earlier* store from the same writer. And that's really about it.

Comment: @ClarkGaebel Always go for sequential consistency (__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST) first, unless you have really, really, really good reasons not to. And even then, it is probably not worth the headache the more relaxed models cause ;)

Comment: @ClarkGaebel: Use sequential consistency. However, as stated in my other comment you haven't specified how you're actually managing this atomic object. If it were `std::atomic` then sequential consistency is the default and you'd be fine, but you may want to expand on your atomic type...

Comment: @ClarkGaebel Regarding what's the point of relaxed mode: Relaxed mode is merely the _absence_ of synchronization, so it's not a feature that needs to be implemented explicitly. That being said, there are rare cases where the relaxed model is enough and the additional performance actually pays off, but they are few and far between.

Comment: Relaxed model at the very least guarantees that each write is indivisible and that no reader can see a partially-stored value (most current architectures provide this by default for word-sized objects, obviously none do for arbitrary-sized objects).

Comment: After doing some [more reading](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics), I think my use case best matches acquire/release semantics. I would load/acquire in my reader threads and store/release in my writer thread. Does this make sense?

Comment: @ClarkGaebel Only if your profiler indicated that there is a serious problem when using seq_cst. Choosing memory orderings is not a best-fit decision. Even professionals who have worked with this for years have trouble writing correct code using the weaker memory models, so I would strongly advise against using anything weaker than seq_cst unless you absolutely have to and are 100% aware of what you are getting into.

Comment: As someone who has spent weeks researching memory models, I will second what @ComicSansMS is saying here: I would never use anything but seq_cst without heavy motivation from profiling of actual input data.

Comment: Well, relaxed ordering **does** guarantee that the written value is eventually visible to the reader threads. There only aren't any happens-before guarantees or a guarantee that the value becomes visible immediately. If "eventually" is good enough, then relaxed ordering is good enough, too. In fact, if you're sure that you do not cross a cache line and are not writing to non-cacheable memory, even a simple non-atomic write would almost certainly be good enough.

Comment: @Damon: Wouldn't the relaxed ordering allow the writer thread to keep all the writes in its L2 cache, and all the reading threads to read it once and use the value in either main memory or THEIR L2 cache?

Comment: @ClarkGaebel: memory_order_relaxed/memory_order_release/etc. give you _absolutely no_ caching benefit.  Either the cache coherence protocol on your machine is giving you benefit or it isn't.  The memory_order_relaxed/memory_order_release things simply allow the compiler to move your atomic load()s and store()s with respect to other instructions in your program.  So if you are using your atomic  object to tell other threads that some other code has run, memory_order_relaxed/release etc. just allows the compiler to move your atomic operations to a point before where that code has actually run.

Comment: Using `memory_order_relaxed`, in particular, tells your compiler that you don't care at all where it moves your modifications to your atomic variable.  It could move them all to the last statement of `main` if it wants to.